# Features Redemption use to work with OST files

Tags: outlook-redemption, pst

As is known, OST and PST files correspond to a single specification of binary Personal Folder File format. Some tools (in particular, PST.NET) allows to read OST file, just as if it were a PST file.

Can I use Redemption to work with the OST to a similar style?

Answer (score 0):

No, Redemption is a wrapper around Extended MAPI, which does not expose anything to open an OST file outside of the profile used to create it.